# File not renameing or deleting

Tags: java

cur file does not seem to be deleted and temp file does not get renamed.

```
private class editClassListener implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                File temp = new File("courseTemp.bin");
                File cur = new File("course.bin");
                ArrayList<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();
                int count = 0;
                try {
                    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(cur);
                    while(true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
                            Course c = (Course) oin.readObject();
                            courses.add(c);
                        }catch (EOFException eofException){
                            break;
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    while(count < courses.size())
                    {
                        if(enterCourseID.getText().equals(courses.get(count).getCourseID()))
                        {
                            courses.get(count).setDescription(enterCourseDescription.getText());
                            courses.get(count).setSemester((String) semesterBox.getSelectedItem());
                            courses.get(count).setYear(yearBox.getSelectedIndex());
                        }
                    }
                    temp.renameTo(cur);
                    cur.delete();
                    temp.delete();
                    fin.close();

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(temp);
                    courses.trimToSize();
                    count = 0;
                    while(count < courses.size())
                    {
                            ObjectOutputStream oop = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                            oop.writeObject(courses.get(count));
                            count++;
                    }

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }
        }
```

Comment: I see you never close any streams what so ever. Might want to do that. `oop.close();` and whatever else streams you use....

Answer (score 0):

Both `File.delete()` and `File.renameTo()` do not throw an Exception but instead return `false` if the underlying OS-operation cannot be executed. Reasons for that are dependant on your system, but include among others:

- The file you are trying to rename/delete is in use (i. e. open streams)
- The file is protected by the OS (insufficient rights)
- In case of renaming: A file with the new name already exists

In your case, at least the first point is true. You should be fine by simply closing your `FileInputStream fin` before trying to delete `cur`. As for the renaming, you might need to delete `cur` first before renaming `temp`.

As an aside, the Utility Class `java.nio.file.Files` offers methods (`move()`&`delete()`) for renaming and deleting, which throw an `IOException`, if the operation fails, with the cause of failure in the error message.

Comment: Thanks for you Information. Closing the FileInputStream, FileOutputStream, and deleting the old file before renaming fixed my problem.